# Eager loading related entities from a table-valued function in NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

So I have a table-valued function in my dabatase that does some heavy and complex query based on several parameters, and returns for example three columns: `OrderId`, `SomeCalc1`,  `SomeCalc2`.

Now in order to translate this into NHibernate, the only solution I have found is to use named queries. My mapping is as follows:

```
<class name="OrderWithSomeExtraInfo">
  <id name="OrderId" column="OrderId"/>
  <many-to-one name="Order" update="false" insert="false">
    <column name="OrderId"/>
  </many-to-one>
  <property name="SomeCalc1" column="SomeCalc1" update="false" insert="false"/>
  <property name="SomeCalc2" column="SomeCalc2" update="false" insert="false"/>
</class>


<sql-query name="GetOrdersWithSomeCalc">
 <return class='MyDomain.OrderWithSomeExtraInfo, MyDomain' alias='o'/>

 <![CDATA[

  SELECT F.SomeCalc1 AS {o.SomeCalc1}, F.SomeCalc2 AS {o.SomeCalc2}, F.OrderId AS {o.OrderId}
  FROM [dbo].[funcSomething] ( :Param1, :Param2, :StartDate, :EndDate ) AS F

 ]]>
</sql-query>
```

And then in code I call with the following:

```
 IEnumerable<OrderWithSomeExtraInfo> query =
         Session.GetNamedQuery("GetOrdersWithSomeCalc")
         .SetString("Param1", p1)
         .SetString("Param2", p2)
         .SetDateTime("StartDate", StartDate)
         .SetDateTime("EndDate", EndDate)
         .Future<OrderWithSomeExtraInfo>();
```

And what I would like to do is, in code, eager fetch also the `Order`property of OrderWithSomeExtraInfo, and also some chained many-to-ones. Something like this:

```
  IEnumerable<OrderWithSomeExtraInfo> query =
         Session.GetNamedQuery("GetOrdersWithSomeCalc")
         .SetString("Param1", p1)
         .SetString("Param2", p2)
         .SetDateTime("StartDate", StartDate)
         .SetDateTime("EndDate", EndDate)
         .Fetch(owse => owse.Order)
         .ThenFetch(o => o.Customer)
         .Future<OrderWithSomeExtraInfo>();
```

However I cannot find the way to do it, since it is not a NHibernate LINQ query. So I don't know how to eager fetch when the origin is a native SQL query, nor how to map a function to the LINQ or QueryOver API.

Answer (score 0):

First I have to apologize, since I do not know very much about NHibernate but since no one answered yet, I will give my best to share some information that I found.

This is a very good article of Aende the creator of NHibernate. He explained how you can use stored procedure with custom SQL and Entities that live in a relation.
https://ayende.com/blog/1692/using-nhibernate-with-stored-procedures

It looks like if you want the association to order and customer (<- that is what I understand) then you have to also model it (or map it in your xml).

In the middle of the article there is the thing you might be looking for. Here is something like `<loader query-ref="allSalariesForEmployee"/>` in the article which should be responsible for the association. This should also be possible if the associated does not come from a stored procedure.

I hope this helps and I did understand you question correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your named query to something like this:

```
  <sql-query name="GetOrdersWithSomeCalc">
    <![CDATA[
      SELECT *
      FROM [dbo].[funcSomething] (:Param1,:Param2,:StartDate,:EndDate ) as F
      JOIN [dbo].[Orders] O ON F.OrderId = O.OrderId
      JOIN [dbo].[Customers] C ON O.CustomerId = C.CustomerId
     ]]>
    <return alias='f' class='MyDomain.OrderWithSomeExtraInfo, MyDomain'/>
    <return-join alias='o' property='f.Order' />
    <return-join alias='c' property='o.Customer' />
  </sql-query>
```

This should '*eagerly*' populate your object *(using your first example, no need for the .Fetch or .FetchNext statements)*.  I extrapolated the table names and Id column names; you may need to tweak them based on your naming convention.

Comment: Yes does that work, but then the eager fetching is limited to those that are mapped, I cannot query them dinamically depending on my needs, or I would need to have several different named queries for the same.